# <title> and window.parent

Tags: php, window, parent, title

my site is a design on index.php and then a frame on it.. Now, i want to do so the titles changes When you browse to eg. Videos.php.

So how should i do this with window.parent and title?

The title needs to be changed on index.php.

So cant it be done like on videos.php:

```
<script>
        window.parent.changeTitle("Videos - Mysite.com"); 
</script>
```

and then on index.php:

```
function changeTitle(msg) {
    <title>(msg)</title>
}
```

just an thought i dont know really..

Comment: please show us how videos.php and index.php work together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
window.parent.document.title = "Videos - Mysite.com";
```

Your code won't work - the function you wrote isn't even syntactically valid. Plus, adding a title tag after the page has loaded would have no effect - you need to change the document title by updating the `document.title` attribute.

Comment: But if the function was valid, would `window.parent.changeTitle("Videos - Mysite.com");` work?